# Resistor network

Tags: resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fasM6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How would I go about finding the voltage at the left side of the Zener diode (Node 1)?

The trace that goes South goes to a 100k resistor that attaches to an OPAMP. Does this effect the calculation?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Where does the other end of the zener diode go?

Comment: Didn't work, but to a positive end of a Cap, Diode, and Optocoupler. The negative end of the cap, diode, and opto go to ground.

Comment: There is a schematic editor that you can use when you edit your post.  It might be easier to use it and include a complete, correct diagram.  The voltage you are interested in depends in part on what the other end of the zener is connected to.

Comment: I didn't know about the circuit design. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: We need the bit to the right of the zener too.

Comment: Updated with schematic editor.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp won't significantly change the answer.  Op-Amps typically have an input impedance of (at least) several 100 thousand ohms - this won't matter when put in parallel with the 2.7k for R3.

Treat R2 and R3 as a voltage divider (ignore Z1 for now) and calculate the voltage at the R2 and R3 junction.

You will find that the voltage is higher than the breakdown voltage of the zener + the forward voltage of the optocoupler LED.

So, end result is that the junction of R2 and R3 is at the sum of the zener reverse voltage (6.3V) and the forward voltage of the LED (from 1.15 to 1.5V according to the MOC3011 datasheet.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, it will not make a significant difference, unless there is a huge negative potential on the opamp input. Realistically no. I am also assuming the the optocoupler diode is the other way around, if not then its a strange circuit and the first part of my answer could be wrong!

Comment: You were correct about the Optocoupler. I was in a hurry while making it.

Comment: The 1k and 2k7 with the 20V input form a source equivalent to about 14.6V with 730ohms source resistance. This will give you about 6.2V + 1Vish = 7.2V at the left of the zener and about 10mA flowing through it.